# How to modify regex to allow brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
[0-9.-]+
```

What do I need to add to allow brackets at any point in the input string? i.e '(' or ')'

Comment: Do you mean brackets [] or parenthesis () or both?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I didn't realize you were in the UK. I think we call them different things across the pond. :)

Comment: can you give some example strings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the regex that support brackets

```
[0-9.\-\[\]]+
```

here is the regex that support parenthesis

```
[0-9.\-\)\(]+
```

and both

```
[0-9.\-\)\(\[\]]+
```

Comment: Escape the `-` like this `\-`, otherwise it's a range (like `[a-f]`).

Comment: Be sure to use the backslash before each bracket

Comment: You can do a couple of things. First, you can declare your string like this @"[0-9.\-\\)\\(]+". Second, you can escape the '\' in the string like this "[0-9.\\-\\\)\\\(]+"

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just add them to the regex with something like `[0-9.\)\(-]+` but, since you're complicating the expression, you'll probably need to check for balance as well.

In other words, that regex is quite happy to accept `74.7((((((((((((2)` which is not really well-formed. But, since you're original accepted `...........2.2.2.22222...`, that may not be a great concern :-)